# Parse a single POJO from multiple YAML documents representing different classes

Tags: java, yaml, deserialization, snakeyaml

I want to use a single YAML file which contains several different objects - for different applications. I need to fetch one object to get an instance of MyClass1, ignoring the rest of docs for MyClass2, MyClass3, etc. Some sort of selective de-serializing: now this class, then that one... The structure of MyClass2, MyClass3 is totally unknown to the application working with MyClass1. The file is always a valid YAML, of course.

The YAML may be of any structure we need to implement such a multi-class container. The preferred parsing tool is snakeyaml.

Is it sensible? How can I ignore all but one object?

UPD: replaced all "document" with "object". I think we have to speak about the single YAML document containing several objects of **different** structure. More of it, the parser knows exactly only 1 structure and wants to ignore the rest.

UDP2: I think it is impossible with snakeyaml. We have to read all objects anyway - and select the needed one later. But maybe I'm wrong.

UPD2: sample config file

```
--- 
- 
  exportConfiguration781: 
    attachmentFieldName: "name"
    baseSftpInboxPath: /home/user/somedir/
    somebool: false
    days: 9999
    expected: 
      - ABC w/o quotes
      - "Cat ABC"
      - "Some string"
    dateFormat: yyyy-MMdd-HHmm
    user: someuser
- 
  anotherConfiguration: 
    k1: v1
    k2: 
      - v21
      - v22
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer of @flyx was very helpful for me, opening the way to workaround the library (in our case - snakeyaml) limitations by overriding some methods. Thanks a lot! It's quite possible there is a final solution in it - but not now. Besides, the simple solution below is robust and should be considered even if we'd found the complete library-intruding solution.

I've decided to solve the task by double distilling, sorry, processing the configuration file. Imagine the latter consisting of several parts and every part is marked by the unique token-delimiter. For the sake of keeping the YAML-likenes, it may be

```
---
#this is a unique key for the configuration A
<some YAML document>
---
#this is another key for the configuration B
<some YAML document
```

The first pass is pre-processing. For the given String fileString and String key (and DELIMITER = "\n---\n". for example) we select a substring with the key-defined configuration:

```
int begIndex;                                                                       
do {                                                                                
  begIndex= fileString.indexOf(DELIMITER);                                          
  if (begIndex == -1) {                                                             
    break;                                                                          
  }                                                                                 
  if (fileString.startsWith(DELIMITER + key, begIndex)) {                           
    fileString = fileString.substring(begIndex + DELIMITER.length() + key.length());
    break;                                                                          
  }                                                                                 
  // spoil alien delimiter and repeat search                                        
  fileString = fileString.replaceFirst(DELIMITER, " ");                             
} while (true);                                                                     
int endIndex = fileString.indexOf(DELIMITER);                                       
if (endIndex != -1) {                                                               
  fileString = fileString.substring(0, endIndex);                                   
}
```

Now we feed the fileString to the simple YAML parsing

```
ExportConfiguration configuration = new Yaml(new Constructor(ExportConfiguration.class))
    .loadAs(fileString, ExportConfiguration.class);
```

This time we have a single document that must co-respond to the ExportConfiguration class.

Note 1: The structure and even the very content of the rest of configuration file plays absolutely no role. This was the main idea, to get independent configurations in a single file

Note 2: the rest of configurations may be JSON or XML or whatever. We have a method-preprocessor that returns a String configuration - and the next processor parses it properly.

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely possible with SnakeYAML, albeit not trivial. Here's a general rundown what you need to do:

First, let's have a look what *loading* with SnakeYAML does. Here's the important part of the `YAML` class:

```java
private Object loadFromReader(StreamReader sreader, Class<?> type) {
    Composer composer = new Composer(new ParserImpl(sreader), resolver, loadingConfig);
    constructor.setComposer(composer);
    return constructor.getSingleData(type);
}
```

The *composer* parses YAML input into *Nodes*. To do that, it doesn't need any knowledge about the structure of your classes, since every node is either a ScalarNode, a SequenceNode or a MappingNode and they just represent the YAML structure.

The *constructor* takes a root node generated by the *composer* and generates native POJOs from it. So what you want to do is to throw away parts of the node graph before they reach the constructor.

The easiest way to do that is probably to derive from `Composer` and override two methods like this:

```java
public class MyComposer extends Composer {
    private final int objIndex;

    public MyComposer(Parser parser, Resolver resolver, int objIndex) {
        super(parser, resolver);
        this.objIndex = objIndex;
    }

    public MyComposer(Parser parser, Resolver resolver, LoaderOptions loadingConfig, int objIndex) {
        super(parser, resolver, loadingConfig);
        this.objIndex = objIndex;
    }


    @Override
    public Node getNode() {
        return strip(super.getNode());
    }

    private Node strip(Node input) {
        return ((SequenceNode)input).getValue().get(objIndex);
    }
}
```

The `strip` implementation is just an example. In this case, I assumed your YAML looks like this (object content is arbitrary):

```yaml
- {first: obj}
- {second: obj}
- {third: obj}
```

And you simply select the object you actually want to deserialize by its index in the sequence. But you can also have something more complex like a searching algorithm.

Now that you have your own composer, you can do

```java
Constructor constructor = new Constructor();
// assuming we want to get the object at index 1 (i.e. second object)
Composer composer = new MyComposer(new ParserImpl(sreader), new Resolver(), 1);
constructor.setComposer(composer);
MyObject result = (MyObject)constructor.getSingleData(MyObject.class);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The problem with the implementation is that the strip() does not work. Exception says ScalarNode cannot be cast to SequenceNode, that is sensible. And, yes, my YAML looks exactly as you've supposed.

Comment: Besides, I cannot get the idea of stripping just one time. What if the obj below has some node trees inside (and it has actually)? How will it be parsed with the strip() active?

Comment: You really should add some example YAML to your question to show how you need it to be stripped.

Comment: I updated the code. Turns out `getSingleNode()` calls `getNode()` so overriding the first one leads to calling `strip()` twice. I'm afraid I don't really have a Java setup for debugging, so please check if it works now for this simple case.

Comment: I've added sample config file. Looking to your changes I still don\t understand the casting in the strip(). It surely will cause the exception.