# Snakeyaml removed quotes

Tags: java, yaml, snakeyaml, raml

How do I configure snakeyaml to remove the following single quotes?

```
#%RAML 1.0 DataType
type: object
properties:
  apiName:
    type: string
  label:
    type: string
  sortable:
    type: '!include boolean-types.raml'
```

I am using snakeyaml to output RAML, I need to remove the single quotes on the include.

I have configured the options as follows:

```
DumperOptions options = new DumperOptions();
options.setIndent(2);
options.setPrettyFlow(true);
options.setDefaultFlowStyle(DumperOptions.FlowStyle.BLOCK);
Yaml yaml = new Yaml(options);
yaml.dump(map, writer);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```yaml
  type: '!include boolean-types.raml'
```

is a key `type` with the scalar value `!include boolean-types.raml`.

This proposed line:

```yaml
type: !include boolean-types.raml
```

is a key `type` with a scalar value `boolean-types.raml`, where the scalar node has the explicit tag `!include`.

They are different in semantics. You are apparently giving SnakeYAML data that contains the former and then expect it to output the latter. That can't work, YAML serialization keeps the semantics of the given data. You need to give data that represents the semantics you want to have in the YAML file.

For example, you could define an `Include` class with a custom representer:

```java
class Include {
    public String path;
}

class IncludeRepresenter extends Representer {
    public IncludeRepresenter(DumperOptions options) {
        super(options);
        this.representers.put(Include.class, new RepresentInclude());
    }

    private class RepresentInclude implements Represent {
        public Node representData(Object data) {
            Include incl = (Include) data;
            return representScalar(new Tag("!include"), incl.path);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can do

```java
Yaml yaml = new Yaml(new IncludeRepresenter(), options);
```

and use an `Include` object where you want to produce the value shown above.

Comment: Thank you, this works well.  It prints it like this type: !include 'boolean-types.raml' instead of this type: !include boolean-types.raml but that is legal in RAML.  One thing, the Representer constructor with no args is deprecated, you have to add the DumperOptions to it.

Comment: @Julie Feel free to propose edits, I'll accept them. I don't have a Java setup on my machine, I copied from the docs and assumed that's up-to-date. Regarding the quotes, you can set the style of the ScalarNode created via `representScalar` before returning it.

Comment: Any idea on how to write this representer so that it can read the !include as well using the load() function?  It would be a game changer for me.

Comment: The representer *represents* data, you'll need a `Constructor` for loading. You can write custom constructors for custom tags like `!include`, but if you want `!include` to work as if the referenced YAML file was part of the document, you should instead [write your own Composer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61885431/347964) (linked answer has a different focus but shows you how to generally do stuff at this point of the loading process). The whole thing is non-trivial and certainly too complex to add to this answer.

Comment: Thank you, you have been so much help, game changer!

Answer (score 0):

To parse the file with the !include you can do the following.

```
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.LoaderOptions;
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.AbstractConstruct;
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor;
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.nodes.Node;
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.nodes.ScalarNode;
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.nodes.Tag;

public class IncludeConstructor extends Constructor {
    public IncludeConstructor(LoaderOptions options) {
        super(options);
        this.yamlConstructors.put(new Tag("!include"), new ConstructIncludeTag());
    }

    private class ConstructIncludeTag extends AbstractConstruct {
        public Object construct(Node node) {
            ScalarNode scalarNode = (ScalarNode) node;
            return "!include " + scalarNode.getValue();
        }
    }
}


Yaml yaml = new Yaml(new IncludeConstructor(new LoaderOptions()));
```